# Cname pointing to Dynamic Subdomain

Tags: php, nginx

I have a laravel application on `www.mydomain.com` on digitalocean using nginx, am working on having a dynamic subdomain features (like tumblr) for users to have their portfolio on `username.mydomain.com`.

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{username}.mydomain.com'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function ($username) {
        # some function here
    })

});
```

Everything works fine and anytime a user visits `username.mydomain.com` their portfolio is rendered.

**The Problem now** is the user has a domain `www.userdomain.com` on webfaction I configured `www.userdomain.com` cname to point to `username.mydomain.com` but anytime I view this page on my browser it doesnt take me to the portfolio of the user instead it takes me to the homepage of `www.mydomain.com`. Please can anyone help me with this.

Comment: http://jokull.calepin.co/nginx-mass-dynamic-hosting.html this will be use full for you.

Comment: thanks @Vigikaran will try that and give u a feedback, But i looks exactly like what i have been looking for. Thanks